# How to complete this simple example of the Vitali-Hahn-Saks Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, limits, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm studying the Vitali-Hahn-Saks Theorem and I need some help with an example in which the conclusion of the theorem fails.

**Theorem.** Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, P)$ be a finite measure space, and let $(P_n)$ a sequence of finite measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ each of which is absolutely continuous with respect to $P$. Suppose the sequence $(P_n(\Omega))$ is bounded. If $(P_n)$ converges setwise to the set function $P_\infty$, then $(P_n)$ is *uniformly* absolutely continuous with respect to $P$ ($\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta>0, \forall n, \forall A \in \mathcal{F}, P(A) < \delta$ implies $P_n(A) < \epsilon$). Moreover, $P_\infty$ is a finite measure that is absolutely continuous with respect to $P$.

I thought I'd cook up a simple example where uniform absolute continuity fails in order to see how setwise convergence fails. Start with a countable probability space given by $P(\omega_n) = 2^{-n}$. Let the events $E_n = \Omega - \cup_{i=1}^n \{\omega_i\}$. And let $P_n = P(\cdot \mid E_n)$. Note that $\inf_n\{P(E_n) \}=0$.

The sequence $(P_n)$ is not uniformly absolutely continuous with respect to $P$. To see that let $\epsilon = 1/2$, and let $\delta > 0$ be given. For large enough $n$, $P(E_n) < \delta$ but $P_n(E_n) = 1 > \epsilon.$

> **Question.** How to see that $(P_n)$ does not converge setwise? I've played around with a few example events $A$, but $(P_n(A))$ always converges. Hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some **hints** about what kind of set $A$ you are looking for:

If $A$ is finite, then eventually $A\cap E_n = \emptyset$, so 
$$
P_n(A)=\frac{P(A\cap E_n)}{P(E_n)} \longrightarrow 0
$$

Thus we are looking for infinite sets. Moreover, if we eventually have $E_n \subset A$ then $A \cap E_n = E_n$ so
$$
P_n(A) = \frac{P(A \cap E_n)}{P(E_n)} = \frac{P(E_n)}{P(E_n)} \longrightarrow 1
$$

Thus we are looking for a set $A$ that has infinitely many "holes" (more precisely, for any $N$ we can find a $n >N$ such that $\omega_n$ is not in $A$).

Can you think of a very simple set $A$ with these properties?

---

Added later:

Elaborating on the hint given above, one of the simplest set to satisfy the properties we want is the set of $\omega_i$ with **even** index. That is, we take
$$
A = \{ \omega_{2 i} : i \geq 1 \}
$$

In this case, after some calculation we find that $P_n(A) = 1/3$ when $n$ is even and $P_n(A) = 2/3$ when $n$ is odd. Consequently, the sequence $P_n(A)$ does not converge.

Comment: Thanks, these are good hints. In fact, your suggestions occurred to me earlier, and I thought I would consider the set $A$ consisting of even-indexed $\omega_n$. I couldn't convince myself that the limit doesn't exist for this $A$, however. But that could very well mean I'm simply messing up the calculations somehow. I'll try again soon.

Comment: Yes, this is the set $A$ I had in mind too. If my calculations are correct, you should get that $P_n(A) = 1/3$ for $n$ even and $P_n(A) = 2/3$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: Ah, really? I got something like that the first time I worked it too. But then I thought I made a mistake, redid it, and got something different. I'll need to sit down with it again and work carefully, as clearly I'm being very sloppy somehow. Thanks again!

Comment: Alright, I think I got it. For odd $n$, $P(A \cap E_n) = \frac{1/2^{n+1}}{3/4}$, so $$P_n(A) = 2^n P(A \cap E_n) = 2/3.$$ For even $n$, $P(A \cap E_n) = \frac{1/2^{n+2}}{3/4}$ and $P_n(A) = 1/3.$ Seems easy now! I think I just got confused with the indexing in my previous attempts.

Comment: Yes, I get the same result! Don't worry, I messed up too the first time I tried to compute it...

Comment: Thanks for your help. Apparently I have to wait 19 hours to award bounty, but I plan to do it.